# Wysiwyg and execCommand(

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I've a problem with my wysiwyg.
Why if I use the button to create the link tag or bold tag, my script gone but when I use the menu it breaks?

Can y help me?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark116/R4t8g/5/)

```
<div contenteditable id="editArea" style="width:400px; height:100px"></div>
<p>
  <input type='button' value='Bold' onclick="add_cmd('bold');"/>
  <input type='button' value='Link' onclick="add_cmd('link');"/>
</p>
<p>
  <a onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, bar_hover, '170px')">Menu Hover</a>
  <a onclick="dropdownmenu(this, event, bar_click, '170px')">Menu click</a>
</p>
```

Please see complete code on link :)

Comment: The jsfiddle link is broken.